# C negation in if-statement?

Tags: c

I am examining a C code for a pressed key in a embedded system.

In the code below you can see an if-statement with ! before checking REG8, what does this mean in a situation like this? I am just asking about the character (!) and not what the code does.

```
if(!(REG8(DataRegA) & 0x80)){ 
*key=REG8(DataRegA) & 0x0F;
return(1); 
}
```

Comment: Any decent C book or tutorial will explain the `!` operator.

Comment: Well, it's just the `!` character. What else are you interested in about it if not what it does?

Comment: @KeithThompson he does not ask for the operator but the contextual meaning

Comment: It means that, if the right-hand-side operand is non-zero return FALSE, otherwise TRUE.

Comment: @HotLicks You mean `0` and `1`.

Comment: @drahnr: "I am just asking about the character (!) and not what the code does."

Comment: @H2CO3 - I mean what I say.  Sometimes.  If I'm in the mood.

Comment: The question is unclear, but if someone (who understands it) wants to edit the title and wording a bit to make it searchable I think this would be a valuable post.

Comment: Side note: I am confident that you do not want to take 2 samples of DataRegA, rather than 1 coherent sample.  Consider `sample = REG8(DataRegA); if(!(sample & 0x80)){ *key=sample & 0x0F; return(1); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code checks the state of the 7th bit in that register; if it's off, it executes the block of code.

- `REG8(DataRegA)` presumably gets the value of some MCU register, which probably reflects the state of some input signal;
- `REG8(DataRegA) & 0x80` performs a bitwise AND with `0x80`, which returns 0 if the seventh bit is not set, `0x80` otherwise;
- the `!` is the logical negation operator; in `!(REG8(DataRegA) & 0x80)` it negates the expression above, i.e. if it's 0 it becomes 1, if it's nonzero it becomes 0.

Thus, the `if` body is executed only if the 7th bit in the register is not set.

Answer (score 2):

that means the button is active on low better known as `active low`

Comment: @0x7fffffff `in this situation` tells you it has a specific context

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to know!

Comment: @Erica And how are we supposed to know the context? "An embedded platform" is non-informative.

Comment: @Erica if it solved your issue, you can accept the answer (given you are new to SO)

Comment: @Erica: But it's not what you asked: "I am just asking about the character (!) and not what the code does."

Comment: @H2C03 drahnr knew, and it is informative, it helps to understand the context situation.

Comment: @Erica One user understanding it is not enough. You should formulate your question so that *anyone* can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The ! operator yields 0 if its operand is nonzero and 1 if its operand is 0, and the if-statement executes its body if the condition is nonzero. So if `REG8(DataRegA) & 0x80` evaluates to 0 (which would make the code in the if-statement's block not execute), the ! operator will reverse it and make it execute.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the boolean *not* operator. So if `<expr>` is true (i.e. non-zero), then `!(<expr>)` is false (zero), and vice versa.